# How to have a complex binding in Aurelia?

Tags: typescript, binding, aurelia

**Edited for typo**

I'm currently trying to get the grips of Aurelia (aurelia.io). It's quite nice so far and overall, I like it but I'm stuck on trying to bind a custom component to the property of a VM.

My VM (YardMap.ts) has a property that is an array of objects:

```
export class YardMap {
...
    locationsData:LocationModel[];
...
}
```

The corresponding view (YardMap.html) uses a component to which I'd like to be able to pass the data from the VM:

```
<template>
    <require from="./resources/map-viewer"></require>
    ...
    <map-viewer id="mapWrapper" class="threeContainer" locationsData.bind="locationsData"></map-viewer>
    ...
</template>
```

And finally, my component itself (map-viewer.ts) has a bindable property of the same type as the one from the VM and a propertychanged handler:

```
@noView()
export class MapViewer {
    @bindable locationsData:LocationModel[] = [];

    locationsDataChanged(newValue:LocationModel[]){
        console.log(newValue.length);
    }
}
```

This last method never gets called. If my property was a primitive, it would work easily but if it's an object or an array of objects, I can't seem to have the binding working.

Any idea?

Comment: I have had no problems binding to objects, haven't needed to bind an array yet. What if you wrote locations-data instead of locationsData in the view? This is the only difference I see between your code and mine. Well. That and @noView, but you said it works with primitives so I would guess arrays should work too. Like this: <map-viewer id="mapWrapper" class="threeContainer" locations-data="locationsData"></map-viewer>

Comment: Damn, I love this site! I banged my head for 2 hours on this problem and I just had to post my question here to have you come and save me from destroying my desk! You're right, I forgot about this convention of camelCase in code, hyphens in templates... Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write locations-data instead of locationsData in the view, like this:

```
<map-viewer id="mapWrapper" class="threeContainer" locations-data.bind="locationsData"></map-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `property.bind` or `property.two-way` (if you want data from view to model too) in view model like that:

```
<map-viewer id="mapWrapper" class="threeContainer" locations-data.two-way="locationsData"></map-viewer>
```

Comment: Yes you're right but that was just a bit I lost while copying the code. I tried with the '.bind'... I'll correct my question.